# How to refresh associated entity in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. Right now, I have two Hibernate entities.

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class EntityA {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<EntityB> listB;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class EntityB {
    ...
    private EntityA a;
    ...
}
```

Let's say I have two portal to update TableB using the function below

```
public void saveB(EntityB b) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction t = null;
        try {
            session = openSession();
            t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(b);
            session.refresh(b);
            t.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback(t);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            closeSession(session);
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I save B via portal 1, it does save to the database, However, when portal 2 load entity A, I didn't see the new record until I save entity A (then, the changes of B shows up). To make the issue clear, an example is if I load entity A page the first time on portal 2, I can see five B records was on the page. Now, I add one more B through portal 1 and then I reload entity A page on portal 2 after I saw the record in database already. However, the page still give me five B records. If I click save now (save entity A), the page reload and then I can see six B records on the page.

I did some research, I think it might be a second level cache issue and see some people said using `CascadeType.REFRESH` might help. But it doesn't. I also tried using `session.refresh(b)` as shown above. It didn't solve the issue. Please help. Thanks.